# Python SMS store program using class and methods - has_been_viewed status

Tags: python, class, methods, sms

```
from datetime import datetime

class sms_store:
    store = []
    read = []
def add_new_arrival(self,number,time,text):
    sms_store.read.append(len(sms_store.store))
    sms_store.store.append(("From: {}, Recieved: {}, Msg: {}".format(number,time,text)))
def delete(self,i):
    try:
        del sms_store.store[i]
    except IndexError:
        print("Index is out of range. Cannot delete")
def message_count(self):
    return print("Amt of messages in inbox: {}".format(len(sms_store.store)))
def viewall(self):
    print(sms_store.store)
def get_unread_indexes(self):
    #### ###################################I need help for this method.
def get_message(self,i)
    print(sms_store.store[i])
### tests ####
time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
my_inbox = sms_store() #instantiate an object 'store' for class
my_inbox.add_new_arrival("12345",time,"Hello how are you?") #instance of store object
my_inbox.add_new_arrival("1111111",time,"BYE BYE BYE")
my_inbox.viewall()
my_inbox.msgcount()
```

Thanks for viewing this.

This is what I need to do:

```
my_inbox.add_new_arrival()
```

When adding a new message, its has_been_viewed status is set False.

```
my_inbox.get_unread_indexes()
```

Returns list of indexes of all not-yet-viewed SMS messages

```
my_inbox.get_message(i)**
```

Return (from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms) for message[i]
Also change its state to "has been viewed".
If there is no message at position i, return None

Please help me on those above methods!?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add another list to your class called unread. Change `add_new_arrival` to add the message to unread.

Then under the `get_message` method move the specified message from unread to read.

Lastly your `get_unread` method just lists the indexes of the unread list.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tweaked your code a bit, I think I have done this before in the "How to think like a computer Scientist Book", Hope it works for you.

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and

```
class SMS_store:
```

then

```
def __init__(self):
    self.store = []


def __str__(self):
    return ("{0}".format(self))

def add_new_arrival(self, number, time, text ):
    self.store.append(("Read: False", "From: "+number, "Recieved: "+time, "Msg: "+text))

def message_count(self):
    return (len(self.store))

def get_unread_indexes(self):
    result = []
    for (i, v) in  enumerate(self.store):
        if v[0] == "Read: False":
            result.append(i)
    return (result)

def get_message(self, i):
    msg = self.store[i]
    msg = ("Read: True",) + msg[1:]
    self.store[i] = (msg)
    return (self.store[i][1:])

def delete(self, i):
    del self.store[i]

def clear(self):
    self.store = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Python SMS store program using class and methods - has_been_viewed status

```
import time
class SMS_store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inbox = []

    def add_new_arrival(self, from_number, text_of_sms,read_status = False):
        number = str(from_number)
        time_received = time.strftime("%D %T")
        self.inbox.append([time_received, number, text_of_sms, read_status])

    def message_count(self):
        return "There are {0} messages in your Inbox".format(len(self.inbox))

    def get_unread_indexes(self):
        unread = []
        for index, message in enumerate(self.inbox):
            if False in message:
                unread.append(index)
        return "Unread Messages in:", unread

    def get_message(self, index):
        message = self.inbox[index]
        message[3] = "Read"
        return message[ : 3]

    def delete(self, index):
        del self.inbox[index]
        return "Deleted Message", index

    def clear(self):
        self.inbox = []
        return "Empty Inbox"
```